# MATLAB: Convert string to number and then back to string

Tags: string, matlab, type-conversion

There is a string containing a number in an arbitrary format (e.g., 12, -34.5, and 6.78e-9). The goal is to convert this string into the corresponding number and then convert this number back to a string such that (a) the precision given in the original string is preserved, and (b) the resulting string has an adequate format (probably, the most adequate format is the format of the original string). I thought the problem could be easily solved using `str2num` and `num2str`; however, in some cases, MATLAB seems to be mangling the final result as shown below:

```
    >> a = '1e23'

    a =

    1e23

    >> b = str2num(a)

    b =

       1.0000e+23

    >> c = num2str(b)

    c =

    9.999999999999999e+22
```

One solution is to use a general format string:

```
    >> c = num2str(b, '%e')

    c =

    1.000000e+23
```

However, in this case, the output looks rather cumbersome for numbers of small orders:

```
    >> d = num2str(1, '%e')

    d =

    1.000000e+00
```

In most cases, `num2str` without additional parameters does a pretty good job resulting in a nicely formatted string. The question is: Is there a way to eliminate the `9.999999999999999e+22` problem?

Thank you!

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: @natan, thanks for the reply. I am aware of the problems due to FP arithmetics.

Comment: can I ask, what's the point? you can save both the string and the number anyway...

Comment: The point is to get a human-friendly string preserving the original precision and without the need of writing a bunch of ad hoc solutions targeted at particular situations.

Comment: so why not  save both the string and the number?

Comment: If you want exactly the same number (and dont want to 'help' people who enter things like 1/2), keeping the string is indeed the best solution. However if you want to perform operations on this you will need to choose a desired output format.

Comment: @natan, the input strings that belong to the same format class can still have undesirable variations within this class, and I would like to unify the output. For example, consider `1e23`, `1e+00023`, `1.0000e23`, `1.000e+023`.

Comment: so you need to set up "rules" that fit to your problem, similar to what @Dennis Jaheruddin just suggested (`format short g`)... It is not clear from the question what these rules are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the representation of one input string does not contain enough information to determine the format. Hence (assuming you want to output slightly different numbers and cannot simply store the number in string format), the simplest way would be to try and find a format that you like.

Judging from your comments, I think you will be happy with:

```
format short g
```

For large numbers it will give:

```
x = num2str(1.0000e+23);str2num(x)

ans =

        1e+23
```

And for small numbers:

```
 x = num2str(1);str2num(x)

ans =

     1
```

Comment: This assumes you just want to represent the number like so. If you actually want different string content try this:   `x = num2str(1e20,'%g')`

Comment: It seems `num2str(..., '%g')` does exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!